# Change blur rate enabled by SetWindowCompositionAttribute

Tags: winapi

I am using an undocumented function SetWindowCompositionAttribute to enable blur behind transparent areas of my window.

However, I would like to control the degree of the blur effect. Is it possible? I can't find anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetWindowCompositionAttribute()` is just a wrapper for the documented [`DwmSetWindowAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969524.aspx) function. There is no DWM attribute, or other DWM API, to change the degree of blurriness.